# Multiple entry Schengen Visa valid for 5 years, with duration of stay : 90 days

Tags: schengen

In July 2015, I have been granted Multiple entry Schengen Visa valid for 5 years, with duration of stay : 90 days.
My job requires me to frequently travel In and Out of Schengen countries,
and have almost consumed 40 days by now, and I am afraid I will soon exhaust these 90 days stay limit.

Question 1: If by chance I exceed 90 days before the expiry in year 2020, what will happen ?

Question 2: Is there any way I can apply to Consulate who issued me this Visa and extend my limit of stay in Schengen, or do I need to apply for another type of Visa for my frequent travel to Schengen?

Comment: wow, i would also love to have this 5 year validity visa because i travel to schengen region atleast once every year. Can you tell if there's anything special that needed to be done to get 5 year validity?

Answer (score 8):

Your 90-day limit applies to any 180-day period, not to the entire 5-year period of the visa's validity.  The maximum number of days you could spend in the Schengen area, therefore, is slightly more than 900.  You must be careful to adhere to the 90/180 rule, though.  There are several questions related to that on this site, including [How does the Schengen 90/180 rule work?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/how-does-the-schengen-90-180-rule-work).

Oddly, the EU's public information pages on Schengen visas don't make this very clear.  The [Schengen Visa Code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex:32009R0810), however, is more explicit, in Annex VII (Filling in the visa sticker), section 4:

> 4. ‘DURATION OF VISIT ... DAYS’ heading:
>
> This heading indicates the number of days during which the visa holder may stay in the territory for which the visa is valid. This stay may be continuous or, depending on the number of days authorised, spread over several periods between the dates mentioned under 2, bearing in mind the number of entries authorised under 3.
>
> The number of days authorised is written in the blank space between ‘DURATION OF VISIT’ and ‘DAYS’, in the form of two digits, the first of which is a zero if the number of days is less than 10.
>
> The maximum number of days that may be entered under this heading is 90.
>
> When a visa is valid for more than six months, the duration of stays is 90 days in every six-month period.

I suspect that this information makes your original questions irrelevant, but for the sake of being thorough, here are the answers:

1. If you exceed the allowed stay under the 90/180 rule, your visa will probably be revoked or annulled.
2. If you have a legitimate reason for spending more than 90 days in a given 180-day period, you may be able to apply for a national ("type D") visa from the country where you will be spending the bulk of your time.  Requirements for these visas vary, however, because they are controlled by national law.  In practice, it is almost certainly easier to spread your travel out so it complies with the 90/180 rule.

Comment: How to read _every_ six-month period? If your visum is valid for 12 months, does that mean 90 days in the first and 90 days in the second 6 months? Or does it mean that in _any_ 6 month period, you should not exceed 90 days? If you would stay for the last theree months in period one followed by the first three months of period two, that would be fine under the first interpretation but not under the second.

Comment: @oerkelens See http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/how-does-the-schengen-90-180-rule-work.  For almost everyone, it means that on any day of presence in the Schengen area, it means you must look at the preceding 179 days, and you may have been present in the Schengen area on no more than 89 days out of those 179.  For citizens of a few countries, the rules are different because of agreements with those countries.  For those countries, the 180-day period starts on the date of first entry, not on the visa's start date.

Comment: Many thanks for such a nice and clear answer, God bless

Comment: @Minoo you're most welcome.  Please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) this answer.  Thank you!