# 3 year Schengen multiple entry visa

Tags: schengen

I've just been awarded a 3 year Schengen multiple entry visa with 90 days "duration of stay".

Does this mean that I only have a total of 90 days to visit the Schengen area over 3 years i.e. each trip counts towards this total?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Multiple entry Schengen Visa valid for 5 years, with duration of stay : 90 days](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/74397/19400), but I earlier voted to close as a duplicate of a different question, so I cannot vote to close it again.  In any event, the answer is that you can stay up to 90 days in any 180-day period.  Any day of presence that is more than 180 days in the past no longer counts toward the 90-day limit.